# Interpolation with np.polyfit()

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am working with data I would like to plot and interpolate. The plotting part works really well.
If the scatter points in the plot would be connected it would give a simple hyperbolic curve like 1/x. So, what I want to do is to interpolate the data to get a 1/x-like curve: y_interp = a * 1/x. This is what I did so far to get there:

```
# define x and y
x_scatter = df_fc['NLPC']*100
ref_line = df_fc.loc[df_fc.index == 1]
y_ref = ref_line['WAR026'].squeeze()
y_scatter = df_fc['WAR026']/y_ref

# scatter the relevant data
ax.scatter(x_scatter, y_scatter, facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')

# defining the values to be interpolated
z = [1/x for x in df_fc['NLPC']]

# interpolation
coeffs = np.polyfit(z, y_scatter, 1)
function = np.poly1d(coeffs)

# define new x_range
min_x = min(df_fc['NLPC']*100)
max_x = max(df_fc['NLPC']*100)
new_x_range = (np.arange(min_x , max_x , 1)).tolist()

values = function(1/new_x_range)
```

But as soon as I run the code an error message appears. The error message reads

```
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

It seems like polyfit creates the error message but I do not know how to cope with that message.
Could you please help me to understand the error message or show me a way around to get an 1/x-curve interpolation?

Regards,
mels

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a zero within that range, and are getting NaN or inf as one of the numbers and numpy is complaining.

After the line `z = [1/x for x in df_fc['NLPC']]`, add:

`z = [x for x in z if np.isfinite(x)]`

If that does not work, you may have a problem with running out of system memory.

Comment: thanks for your quick help. I implemented it and run the code in Python 3.8. The result says `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. I dont think it is a system memory problem there must be enough space.

Comment: @mels I was using a feature numpy has that python lists do not; I did not realize that `z` is a list at that point. I edited in a fix. Try my updated version.